# Send from secondary E-Mail-Address in Echange 2013 / Outlook 2013

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013, outlook-2013

We are running an Exchange 2013 Server with Outlook 2013 as Clients.

On some accounts we need multiple E-Mail-Addresses. We configured them in ECP and gave the users *Send as* and *Full Access* permissions for their Mailbox, just in case.

They receive E-Mails on these addresses, however, we want them to be able to send from them.

Now here's the thing:

- When they send from a secondary address in OWA, everything's working
  fine
- When they try to do the same in Outlook, they get a permissions Error (0x80070005-0x0004dc-0x000524)

We already waited long enough, just in case it had to do with replication.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain exactly that you did?
Have you created additional mailboxes, or just added the addresses to the existing mailbox? 
It should like the former, but if it is the latter, then that doesn't work.

If the former, how are you selecting the address to send as within Outlook? Entering the email address in the from line rarely works - similarly neither does using a nicknames entry. Selecting from the GAL is the best option. If you are using Outlook 2010 or higher, adding the adding mailboxes as an additional ACCOUNT within Outlook will give you an easy drop down list for the From field.

Comment: We added a secondary mail-address to an already existing mailbox.
Which is what I think should give users multiple addresses for one account. It works on the receiving side, also sending works from OWA, just not in Outlook. We have been going with the multiple account approach in the past, buit since we founf out that OWA is able to send mails by changing the From-field, we thought it would be possible to make Outlook do the same..

Comment: Sorry to say, that doesn't do what you want it to do. OWA shouldn't be doing it either - I would check the receiving end. 
As far as Exchange is concerned, you only have one email address for sending - the default. All others are aliases for inbound email only. You cannot pick and choose using the from field.

Comment: You need to create additional mailboxes, grant Send As and Full Mailbox permissions to the primary Windows account, then add them as additional ACCOUNTS in Outlook. That will allow you to choose the address.

Comment: Well, it works from OWA....don't know why.

However I will keep going with separate mailboxes. Thanks Sembee, answer marked as accepted.